# How to define a Subset of a Angular FormGroup?

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider this example:

I have a `form1` and `form2` with multiple FormControls, but they share the common FormControl `id`

Now, I want to give this form as an argument to a method that should only know about the `id` property.

How can I type hint, the parameter for `myMethod()`? I want to make sure, that the parameter of `myMethod` is a FormGroup with a FormControl with the name `id` but with any (optional) additional FormControls.
I tried `FormGroup<{id: FormControl}>` but this does not work. The error is:

```js
TS2345: Argument of type 'FormGroup<{ id: FormControl<any>; name: FormControl<any>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormGroup<{ id: FormControl<any>; }>'.
Property 'name' is missing in type '{ id: FormControl<any>; }' but required in type '{ id: FormControl<any>; name: FormControl<any>; }'.
```

What is the correct way to type hint the `form` with only the `id`?

```js
export class AppComponent {
  readonly form1 = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl(),
  });
  readonly form2 = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
    title: new FormControl(),
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myMethod(this.form1); // Throws error
    this.myMethod(this.form2); // Throws error
  }

  myMethod(form: FormGroup<{id: FormControl}>) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Do both calls throw the exact same error ?

Comment: You can use a generic like this: https://tsplay.dev/NnlYdW

Answer (score 2):

use [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

```
method(control:AbstractControl)
{
    console.log(control.get('id').value)

    //you can also "cast" to formGroup
    const formGroup=control as FormGroup

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few methods, not all of which seem to be created equal.

##### 1. Mapped Type

My preferred method is this:

```
myMethod(form: MyForm) {
  const id = form.controls.id //works.
}

interface MyForm extends FormGroup<{id: FormControl}> {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

It's nice, simple, readable, and works well for most situations. It says, more or less, "We're using a `FormGroup<{id: FormControl}>`, and by the way it might have a bunch of other stuff we don't care about.

##### 2. Partial

If you want a simple one-liner that gives you autocomplete on `form.controls.id` and doesn't complain, this works... acceptably well, too. But it doesn't have full type safety, because all properties are treated as optional, which.. may be a problem, and therefore I wouldn't recommend it unless you need something quick-and-dirty.

```
myMethod(form: Partial<FormGroup<{id: FormControl}>>) {
   const id = form.controls.id //works.
}

//Examples:
myMethod('test') // Doesn't work, because it has nothing at all in common with FormGroup<{id: FormControl}>
myMethod({valid:true}) // Works, because all parameters are optional and it has at LEAST one property that FormGroup<{id: FormControl}> has.
```

Answer (score 1):

##### TLDR: Check [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emmf2j?file=src/app/app.component.ts) only [extending](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) interfaces.

---

No special magic needed, this can be done only by declaring and extending the correct interfaces.

This answer works because `myMethod` uses `{ controls: IBaseForm }` instead of `FormGroup`, the method declaration requires only to fulfill the `id` parameter and not everything else. And also, because every `FormGroup` has an explicit interface defined (**no inferred types**).

First, make sure both forms share the one that makes them share `id`:

```js
// declaring a common interface and extending it is a recommendation; not actually needed as you can just declare its separate properties
export interface IBaseForm {
  id: FormControl<number>;
}
export interface IForm1 extends IBaseForm {
  name: FormControl<string>;
}
export interface IForm2 extends IBaseForm {
  title: FormControl<string>;
}

export class AppComponent {
  readonly form1: FormGroup<IForm1> = new FormGroup({ id... });
  readonly form2: FormGroup<IForm2> = new FormGroup({ id... });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myMethod(this.form1); // No error
    this.myMethod(this.form2); // No error
  }

  myMethod(form: { controls: IBaseForm }) {
    console.log('>> id: ', form.controls.id.value);
  }
}
```

As you can see, `id` is the only available control:
[image]